# Substitution of data in laravel output

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I design a small database in laravel, there was a question of substituting values from the model.

My steps are as follows. There are two bases with values for example automobile brands, and there is a base of car owners.
Accordingly, the first base has the form

```
Id, description

7, bmw

9, audi
```

The second

```
Id, ownername, brandid

1, John, 7

2, leo, 9
```

And I substitute the data in the template, giving the $owners array obtained by the $owners->all() method;
How to correctly replace the brand's id with its description to get `2, leo, audi`?
Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many , https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators have a look here. i think these can help you without using an subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Create the relationship in the Owner model

```
public function brand() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brandid');
}
```

Then if you get one of them you call the relationship in your template

```
$owner = Owner::find(1);

//in template
{{ $owner->brand->description }} //echo 'bmw' because owner 1 has 'brandid' 7
```

If you get many owner, you use a loop

```
$owners = Owner::get();

//in template 
@foreach($owners as $owner)
    {{ $owner->brand->description }}
@endforeach
```

In your foreach loop however, if you have 1000 users, you will make 1000 queries. If you are only working with small amount of users, that's ok. But for large sets of data, eager load owners and brands like

```
$owners = Owner::with('brand')->get();
```

You foreach remains unchanged, but with just 2 queries instead of 1000

Answer (score 1):

With [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations):

Firstly, create the relationship:

```
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand');
}
```

Secondly, specify the relationship been eager loaded:

```
$owners = App\Owner::with('brand')->get();
```

Now you can use the result in your blade or somewhere:

```
foreach ($owners as $owner) {
    echo $owner->brand->description;
}
```